# How to build ReactiveList in multi-threaded manner in CreateDerivedCollection method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to WPF and trying to improve an application.

This WPF application that has bunch of small operations working in the background that creates a poor user experience. I am trying to fix this issue by making these small operations working in their own individual threads.

I have tried to create async function that would run in the background but somehow it doesn't start.

```
Verts = new ReactiveList<VertTemplate>();
VertTemplates = Verts.CreateDerivedCollection(BuildTemplate);
```

Basically BuildTemplate() is a function works on the items in the ReactiveList and returns new items to replace them. But it's working on them in one thread which slows down the process.

I want the reactive list to work on these items in a parallel manner where each of them would work in their own threads. 
Is this possible to do this with DerivedCollections in .net?

I have already tried to adding `scheduler: RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler` but it doesn't work. Or I couldn't figure out how to plug this.

Answer (score 1):

We deprecated reactivelist a while back. It's not thread safe. The replacement is. https://GitHub.com/rolandpheasant/dynamicdata